# Setting default units of measure for new documents in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel, units

Is there a way to set pixels and pixels per inch as the default units of measure and resolution when creating a new document in Photoshop? It's strange that Adobe chose centimeters as the default as almost all documents dimensions are given in pixels. It's good to have a choice but Photoshop doesn't remember that I set pixels last time and I have to change units of measure every time I create a new document, which is a waste of time. There is a "Units and Rulers" tab in Preferences with pixels and pixels per inch set for document presets but still when I create a new document the units are set to centimeters and pixels per centimeter.

Comment: I think you meant 'pixels per centimeter' at the end -- centimeters per inch is a constant that has been fixed at 2,54 for a while ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a setting like this will stick for new documents if you change it *with no documents open*. This also goes for defaults like foreground and background colours, default fonts, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

## Preferences > Units & Rulers

You can set defaults there.

Note that Photoshop tend to *remember* the last used setting. However, if your preferences are set to use Pixels/Inch then it should default to that for *new* documents. Unless, you are using a non-US version of the app. Then it may default to cm.

Comment: I don't think Units&Rulers have anything to do with a New Documents window... PS just remembers the last used settings as you mentioned. I've tried to change Units to various values but new document window was still using the last used settings

Comment: Yeah I kind of remember that it simply remembers the last setting.. in which case, it simply takes opening a new document, setting things how you want, then closing the new document. It'll be set correctly the next time you open a new document.